# Routing error updating/creating record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have what seems to me as a weird routing error that I can't seem to resolve. I'm using Rails 4.2.6 and generating a scaffold for customers. I'm able to view a listing of customers but when I edit a customer I get an error

`No route matches [POST] "/customers/49"`

Everything is pretty much what the scaffolding created though I did change my routes to this:

```
  resources :customers do
    resources :comments, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  end
```

but I tried it with the scaffolding default as well and receive the same error.

These are the routes for customers:

```
               customers GET    /customers(.:format)                                customers#index
                         POST   /customers(.:format)                                customers#create
            new_customer GET    /customers/new(.:format)                            customers#new
           edit_customer GET    /customers/:id/edit(.:format)                       customers#edit
                customer GET    /customers/:id(.:format)                            customers#show
                         PATCH  /customers/:id(.:format)                            customers#update
                         PUT    /customers/:id(.:format)                            customers#update
                         DELETE /customers/:id(.:format)                            customers#destroy
```

The generated HTML for the "edit" page shows it is a post request

```
<form class="edit_customer" id="edit_customer_49" action="/customers/49" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
```

and the same for the "new" page

```
<form class="new_customer" id="new_customer" action="/customers" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
```

For the most part everything is what the scaffolding produced so I'm not sure why I'm getting the error. Why is the generated HTML using a POST and how can I get this working?

Thanks for helping a Rails newbie.

**UPDATE**
Okay, in my model I have

```
CUSTOMER_TYPE = ["A", "B"]
```

In my edit/new form I have this:

```
  <%= f.label :customer_type %>
  <%= f.select :customer_type, Customer::CUSTOMER_TYPE, {include_blank: true}, {index: nil} %>
```

If I take the above line out of my form, both the edit and new forms work without error!?

Comment: It's a POST form, but the method should be coming through as a PATCH. Does your generated HTML have a line like `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">` ?

Comment: Yes @GoGoCarl, I do see that.
`<form class="edit_customer" id="edit_customer_1" action="/customers/1" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="g26xmf0NV5AVBS5hTK1ZqTz2r/PwbA0OXTnQjKN45951ivyGzQ9wnCspZCQ+4c9LQRwmrYys+cdFpKWHr7eJ8w==" />`

Comment: Mack did you figure it out?

Comment: I have not @bkunzi01. Still working on it.

Comment: @mack Ok, so the form's HTML looks decent enough. In your `customers_controller`, have you declared a method `def update` to handle the call?  Also, does the new customer form work, or is it having the same issue?

Comment: @GoGoCarl the "new" form was not working, I was getting an authenticity token error. I removed a couple lines from my view and both the update and new forms started working. I'm still confused as to why it wasn't working and why removing the field from my form caused it to start working. I added the additional info to my question.

Comment: @mack Assuming your model does have a `customer_type` attribute, I think the `CUSTOMER_TYPE` array should be something like `[ ["A", 1], ["B", 2] ]` where the 1 and 2 are supplied IDs that will be used as the value you get back on save.  If you want to save the values as "A" and "B", your entries would be `["A", "A"]`, etc. The first item is the display name, the second the value.

Answer (score 0):

Hey your routes listed show they expect either a PATCH or PUT request for 'updating' so you must change the method to 'PUT' instead of "POST" for this to work properly.  Show the form in your view and I'll show what you to change in more detail.